# How to ensure that a vector of date numbers is fully contained in another in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, date, vector

I have two vectors `A` and `B` containing date numbers. In theory, all coefficients in `B` should also be contained in `A`. Unfortunately this is not the case. My theory justifies replacing all non-corresponding date numbers with the next date number in the `A` vector, for which I would like to write a script.

More concretely: Both vectors contain dates of financial transactions. Vector `A` contains all trading days of the time period examined so that all of the transaction dates in `B` should also be contained in `A` because transactions cannot take place on non-trading days. Where an entry in `B` is not in `A` I hypothesise that trades were mistakenly reported to have taken place on a non-trading day and I would thus like to replace these dates with the next highest number that is contained in `A`.

To provide an example, I would like to turn this:

```
A = [2;3;4;7]
B = [2;3;4;5;6;7]
```

Into this:

```
A = [2;3;4;7]
B = [2;3;4;7;7;7]
```

So that `B(4:5)` were modified because they are not contained in `A`. The script would have to identify that `5` is not contained in `A` and it would then check whether `5+i` is contained in `A` until this evaluates to true (which is the case at `7`). At this point the coefficient would be inserted into `B` to replace the old date.

Note that this question is closely related to [this earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29523090/how-to-identify-date-numbers-corresponding-to-non-business-days-and-replace-them); however it is not identifying business days that this question is about. Instead I want to accept one of my date vectors (`A`) as authoritative (i.e. adequately representing trading days including national holidays) and base the substitution of the non-conforming entries on the `A` vector instead of a Bloomberg function.

Comment: Hi @Constantin you have multiple of your questions still open without an accepted answer.When a answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This solution assumes that `a` and `b` are already sorted.  If not, then simply replace them with `sort(a)` and `sort(b)`.

```
a = [ 2; 3; 4; 7 ];
b = [ 2; 3; 4; 5; 6; 7 ];

% Check each element in b
for k = 1: length(b)

    % If this element of b is not contained in a
    if (all(a(:) ~= b(k)))

        % Replace with the next element in a that is greater than b(k)
        b(k) = a(find(a(:) > b(k), 1, 'first'));
    end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You can apply [`bsxfun`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) to compare each element of `A` with each element of `B`, and then use the second output of [`max`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/max.html) to find the required indices:

```
[~, ind] = max(bsxfun(@le, B(:).', A(:)), [], 1);
B_result = A(ind);
```

This assumes that for each element of `B` there is at least one element in `A` which is greater or equal. Values need not be integer or sorted. For example,

```
A = [2; 3.5; 4.5; 7; 10];
B = [0.1; 2; 2; 6; 5; 4.5];
```

gives

```
B_result =
    2.0000
    2.0000
    2.0000
    7.0000
    7.0000
    4.5000
```